# Can I make a commercial JAVA GUI interface to a GPL2 licensed R package that I authored?

Tags: gpl-2

I authored an R package that will be licensed under GPL2 due to some dependencies that I use also being GPL2. I was wondering if I would be allowed to make a commercial closed source JAVA GUI interface though to use this R package in a user-friendly way, or would that also have to have a GPL2 license? It would just be a GUI that would drive some of the functions from that package via the command line (for users that don't like command-line stuff), e.g. allowing one to select files to be analyzed and select a few analysis options and maybe view the analysis output...

Comment: Since you wrote the GPL code, you should be able to re-licenses via the LGPL which may make this more clear cut and easier to deal with.  IANAL, but I'd think if your GPL works stand alone and your GUI program is simply `shell_exec("your_gpl_code --option value --data=1,3,4,6")` and then capturing out put and doing something with it that the GPL would even come into play...

Comment: Related: [When does a dependency imply a derivative work?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4389/when-does-a-dependency-imply-a-derivative-work)

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between an “aggregate” and other kinds of “modified versions”?](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#MereAggregation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can LGPL and proprietary licenses be combined?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4357/how-can-lgpl-and-proprietary-licenses-be-combined)